# If my math is right this should be centered, right?

Tags: html, css

From what I read, padding expressed as a % calculates based on the parent container (just like the margin does). So, if that's the case then the 3 elements below should be evenly spaced across the parent div. But, they are not.

If I'm doing my math right, you have the width split up like this:

**2%**  padding left

**2%**  padding right

**12%** (4% x 3)  margin left of all three elements

**12%** (4% x 3)  margin right of all three elements

**72%** (24% x 3)  width of all three elements

---

**100%**  sum of all the percents, therefore the three elements should be spread evenly.

Am I missing something? Is padding not calculated this way? Is my math wrong?

```css
#parent {
    background-color: #F00;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 850px;
    padding: 2%;
}
.element {
    background-color: #0F0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 24%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percentages in [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property), [`padding-*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) and [`margin-*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) are resolved relatively to the [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

In the case of your `.element` items, the containing block is the **content edge** of `.parent`. Not the padding or margin one, so it does not include the `padding: 2%` on `.parent`.

If your `.element` were for example absolutely positioned (and `.parent` was relatively positioned), their containing block would be the **padding edge** of `.parent`, like you want. Of course, this would take `.element` completely [out of flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23) and mess your layout.

```css
#parent {
  background-color: #F00;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 850px;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.element {
  background-color: #0F0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 24%;
  left: 06%; /* [[2% + 4%]]+24%+4% + 4%+24%+4% + 4%+24%+4% + 2% */
}
.element + .element {
  left: 38%; /* [[2% + 4%+24%+4% + 4%]]+24%+4% + 4%+24%+4% + 2% */
}
.element + .element + .element {
  left: 70%; /* [[2% + 4%+24%+4% + 4%+24%+4% + 4%]]+24%+4% + 2% */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, so in other words, the padding is not part of the calculated width? I assumed it was calculated from the border.

Comment: @JonathanGrant Usually, not. And that's good. Percentages in content are resolved relatively to content area. If it was padding area, a child with `width: 100%` would overflow.

Comment: Note that a child with `width: 100%`, no margin and a padding of 2% would overflow only with `box-sizing: content-box`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @JoostS I was assuming no paddings. Otherwise yes, with `box-sizing: content-box` it will overflow even if the percentage is resolved relatively to the content area of the parent block.

Answer (score 3):

Note, a percentage `padding` or `margin` is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block.

What is a [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block)?

> In CSS 2.1, many box positions and sizes are calculated with respect to the **edges** of a rectangular box called a containing block. In general, generated boxes act as containing blocks for descendant boxes; we say that a box "establishes" the containing block for its descendants. The phrase "a box's containing block" means "the containing block in which the box lives," not the one it generates.

In your example `#parent{padding:2%;}` is calculated based on its parent `body` element in this case, not `#parent` itself, especially when the viewport's width is greater than the `850px`.

Also, the total width including left and right margin of `.element` divs are always taking up 96% of the edges of the containing block `#parent`.

Therefore, your total calculation of `100%` is not correct. See the updated demo below.

```css
#parent {
  background-color: #F00;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 850px;
}
.element {
  background-color: #0F0;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(68% / 3);
  margin: 4%;
}
.element:first-child {
  margin-left: 8%
}
.element:last-child {
  margin-right: 8%
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `padding: 2%;` on `#parent` refers to 2% of the width of the containing block, not `#parent` itself.

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Comment: I think it refers to the available content space in the parent (width minus padding). What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The elements are taking up 96% of the parent container, not 100%. To be spread evenly they'd need to be taking up 100% of the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.

First of all the obvious one that `padding: 2%` refers to the parent, thus  cannot be added in such a way.

Secondly, you probably want the parent to be 850px wide. There is the box model that comes into play. You need to use `box-sizing: border-box` as this means that the padding is included in the width.

Finally, the element-width in percentage refers to the **available space in the parent**, making 25.3333% the correct value (as 25.333% + 8% = 33.333%).

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aZdyox

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want [image: 6x + 3y = 100] where [image: x] is the integer margin width and [image: y] is the integer box width.

There are no integer combinations of [image: x] or [image: y] that will equal 100.

So basically you cannot do what you want with these constraints.

Comment: CSS [numbers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-number) are not necessary integers.

Comment: @Oriol That is true. I forgot about that. Well dag nab it.